# vba Macro to Read String with delimited and non delimited spaces

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a .txt document that has table information as follows

```
Recipient                    PanelSize                  NumberOfAlerts

Michigan Regional             42454                      15756
Wellcare                      21234                       8492
Michigan Patient Care          6789                       1056
```

I am using a VBA macro to read the .txt file and input into an Excel sheet.

I am having problems mainly with the Recipient. The recipient names contain spaces, so using

```
vDatavalues = Split(sLine, " ")
```

separates Recipients like

```
Michigan|       |Patient|        |Care|
```

which I do not want.

How can I split the lines I am reading to format into the 3 columns correctly reading line by line from the table?

EDIT: Here is an example of the .txt files I am trying to read and format [TEST.txt](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B49EE8B8E5559AE!107&authkey=!AKWEjCRLeUITplU&ithint=file%2ctxt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
Dim sLine As String
sLine = "Michigan Patient Care          6789                       1056"

'Remove all double spaces
Do While InStr(sLine, "  ") <> 0
    sLine = Replace(sLine, "  ", " ")
Loop

'Split using space delimiters
Dim splitLine() As String
splitLine = Split(sLine, " ")

'Collect recipient pieces 
'(i.e. all pieces but the last two, which we know are PanelSize and NumberOfAlerts)
Dim splitRecipient() As String
ReDim splitRecipient(0 To UBound(splitLine) - 2)
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(splitRecipient)
    splitRecipient(i) = splitLine(i)
Next i

'Join recipient pieces
MsgBox "Recipient: " & Join(splitRecipient, " ") & vbCrLf & _
    "PanelSize: " & splitLine(UBound(splitLine) - 1) & vbCrLf & _
    "NumberOfAlerts: " & splitLine(UBound(splitLine))
```

[image]

But really, if your file is in fixed width format, with columns always having the same width and padded with spaces, then it's much easier. In your example, the first column looks like it's 30 chars wide, and the second, 27. So in this case, you could do this:

```
Dim sLines() As String
ReDim sLines(1 To 3)
sLines(1) = "Michigan Regional             42454                      15756"
sLines(2) = "Wellcare                      21234                       8492"
sLines(3) = "Michigan Patient Care          6789                       1056"

Dim iLine As Long
For iLine = LBound(sLines) To UBound(sLines)
    MsgBox "Recipient: " & Trim(Mid(sLines(iLine), 1, 30)) & vbCrLf & _
        "PanelSize: " & Trim(Mid(sLines(iLine), 31, 27)) & vbCrLf & _
        "NumberOfAlerts: " & Trim(Mid(sLines(iLine), 58))
Next iLine
```

The first line is then parsed as:

[image]

Comment: is each record on a new line?  The OP's unformatted data looked like the data didn't have any line breaks in it, in which case this wouldn't work.  Otherwise, if each entry is on a new line, then this is good.

Comment: @Michael: OP's data *looked* like it had no line breaks  -- but OP had indeed typed line breaks in the question. They just didn't show when looked at through the Stack Overflow parser. Once formatted as code they did show. Have a look at the edit history if you want to convince yourself!

Comment: Well, now the problem becomes trivial.  I was seeing if there was a way of implementing a RegExp to search for a `Recipient, PanelSize, NumberOfAlerts` combination, but that was extremely difficult.